# How to call JSON data “@”

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

my url json is @_____ ,but i can't to call this. how to get it ?
thanks you for your answers.

```
 "    RESULT":{
          "FACET":[{ "@NAME" : "creator", "@COUNT" : "20",
            "FACET_VALUES":[
            {
              "@KEY":"Book Company1",
              "@VALUE":"13"},
            {
              "@KEY":"Book Company1์",
              "@VALUE":"10"}
            ]
```

.

```
this.http.get("my_url")
            .subscribe(data =>{
                     this.items=data.json().RESULT.FACET.FACET_VALUES;
            },error=>{
                console.log(error);
            } );
```

.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemClicked($event,item)">
      <h2>{{item.@KEY}}</h2> /////this error 
      <p>{{item.@VALUE}}</p> /////this error 
      <button ion-button clear item-right (click)="buttonClick($event)">View</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in JavaScript, you'd use `item["@KEY"]`. But I don't know if that works with this framework's template language.